# Python for loop to manipulate list and remove elements once used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists where I need to move the second and third element to be put in to the first element (which is a list) in first and last place respectively. I then need to remove the elements once used.

I already have a for loop which will work for the first instance, but I am unsure how to safely remove these elements and move to the next set and repeat operation. I understand for loops are not good for removing elements.

Example list

```
x = ['string 1', 1, 2, 'string 2', 0, 'string 3'], 'new string 1', 'new string 2', ['string 3', 19, 2, 'string 4', 0, 'string 5'], 'new string 3', 'new string 4', ['string 6', 1, 2, 'string 7', 0, 'string 8'], 'new string 5', 'new string 6', ['string 9', 19, 2, 'string 10', 0, 'string 11']
```

where `new string 1` should be put in front of `string 1` and `new string 2` is appended to the list, then all first 10 values (technically the first 3 elements as the first is a list) are removed.

The following for loop achieves this for one instance

```
def sorting_insert_list(x):

        x = list(x)
        for i in range(len(x)):
                keyword = x[1]
                location = x[2]
        x[0].append(location)
        x[0].insert(0, keyword)

        print(x)
```

and returns the following results

```
[['new string 1', 'string 1', 1, 2, 'string 2', 0, 'string 3', 'new string 2'], 'new string 1', 'new string 2', ['string 3', 19, 2, 'string 4', 0, 'string 5'], 'new string 3', 'new string 4', ['string 6', 1, 2, 'string 7', 0, 'string 8'], 'new string 5', 'new string 6']
```

The final list I require would look like the following:

```
sorted_list = ['new string 1', 'string 1', 1, 2, 'string 2', 0, 'string 3','new string 2',]   ['new string 3''string 3', 19, 2, 'string 4', 0, 'string 5', 'new string 4',], ['new string 5','string 6', 1, 2, 'string 7', 0, 'string 8','new string 6']
```

It may be worth noting I will be doing this for a huge list, I have just simplified the data to show as an example. Thanks.

Adding attempt to incorporate date, which appears then in the list after `new string 2` and in the position x[3] :

```
def sorting_insert_list(x):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(3)):
        keyword = x[i + 1]
        location = x[i + 2]
        date = insert_values[i + 3]
        result += [[keyword] + x[i] + [location] + date]
    x = result
    print(x)
```

Comment: Apologies, updated the list ```x```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is abandon original list `x`, and create a new list to compose your result, instead of removing 2nd, 3nd elements from list, you can try this:

```
# list comprehension, more pythonic
def sorting_insert_list(x):
    x = [[x[i+1]] + x[i] + [x[i+2]] for i in range(0, len(x) // 3 * 3, 3)]
    print(x)

# base on your version
def sorting_insert_list(x):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(x) // 3 * 3, 3):
        keyword = x[i + 1]
        location = x[i + 2]
        result += [[keyword] + x[i] + [location]]
    x = result
    print(x)
```

test:

```
x = [['string 1', 1, 2, 'string 2', 0, 'string 3'], 'new string 1', 'new string 2',
     ['string 3', 19, 2, 'string 4', 0, 'string 5'], 'new string 3', 'new string 4',
     ['string 6', 1, 2, 'string 7', 0, 'string 8'], 'new string 5', 'new string 6',
     ['string 9', 19, 2, 'string 10', 0, 'string 11']]

sorting_insert_list(x)
```

output:

```
[['new string 1', 'string 1', 1, 2, 'string 2', 0, 'string 3', 'new string 2'], ['new string 3', 'string 3', 19, 2, 'string 4', 0, 'string 5', 'new string 4'], ['new string 5', 'string 6', 1, 2, 'string 7', 0, 'string 8', 'new string 6']]
```

by the way, `len(x) // 3 * 3` is used to ignore the tail which is less than 3, like your example. If you assure `len(x) % 3 == 0`, you can just use `len(x)`

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thanks a lot works great! I went for the second example just as it was a bit easier for me to understand! also I used the ```len(x)``` as you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: I write the second version in case you are unfamiliar with python. glad it helps you. : )

Comment: I also need to append a ```date``` value to the end of the list but I am getting the following error ```TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "datetime.date") to list```. I update code above to show what I am doing to try and achieve this.

Comment: use `append`, instead of `+=` may help you